# React component with variable from localStorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so I have a pretty simple component:

```
const in_cart = (
    <CartItems>
    <ItemInCart>
      <InCartFont>{ITEM NAME}</InCartFont>
      <CartRemove>
        <CartX>x</CartX>
        <br></br>
        remove
      </CartRemove>
    </ItemInCart>
  </CartItems>)
```

and I'm wondering if there is a way to use it somehow like this:

```
function App() {
  let items_in = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('products')).length;
  for (i = 0; i === items_in; i++) {
    return (
      in_cart(i)
    )
  }
};

ReactDOM.render( <App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('products')) gives this:

```
(10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, ... , {…}]
0: {itemName: ""}
1: {itemName: ""}
2: {itemName: ""}
3: {itemName: ""}
4: {itemName: "Blekk BROTHER LC1280XLC blå"}
5: {itemName: "Blekk BROTHER LC1280XLM rød"}
6: {itemName: "Blekk BROTHER LC1280XLY gul"}
7: {itemName: "Blekk BROTHER HCBK 30K sort"}
8: {itemName: ""}
9: {itemName: ""}
10: {itemName: ""}
```

I want to render my component with {ITEM NAME} read from local storage, something like this I guess:

```
let {ITEM NAME} = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('products'))[i]
```

Comment: In theory, this all makes sense. Is this the actual code you attempted running? Was there an error? Or what ended up being rendered?

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there:

```
function CartItem(props) {
  return (
    <ItemInCart>
      <InCartFont>{props.item.itemName}</InCartFont>
      <CartRemove>
        <CartX>x</CartX>
        <br></br>
        remove
      </CartRemove>
    </ItemInCart>
  );
}

function App() {
  // don't need the length here, let's just get the items
  let items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('products'));

  // since we have an array, we can map over every item
  return (
    <CartItems>
      {items.map((item, index) => {
        return <CartItem item={item} key={index} />
      })}
    </CartItems>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render( <App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I'm assuming all your other components in your JSX are real components, and I'm not going to edit anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sandbox sample: [https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-edison-nep4e](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-edison-nep4e?fontsize=14)

Comments are in code but quick notes are:

- `Array.prototype.map` is the most convenient way to display a list of items in React
- You can use short circuiting to conditionally display items in a list
- React will want a key for each item in a list so it knows which is which.
- If you're rendering a component, it must have a capital name. That's how react knows it's a component and not an html element/custom web component.
- Whenever you want to pass data to a component, you can do so with `props`!